# Linking Cloud DNS to LoadBalancer Ingress

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've got a load-balanced nginx test configuration running, able to hit http servers using the LoadBalancer Ingress IP from WWW. Also have Cloud DNS setup to resolve a domain name. What's the "right" way to connect traffic from Cloud DNS to LoadBalancer Ingress IP? Assuming I need a static IP for DNS - is it just a matter of entering the Ingress IP into the Cloud DNS A Record? That does work, but is it a "good thing", or is there something I'm not considering...like maybe ephemeral service IPs breaking it...thanks!

--
Added info:
There's this

[Setting Up DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/setting-up-dns)

which describes assigning a VM ip address to the DNS A record, but I'm wondering about what happens when that VM (or in my case LoadBalancer) goes down/is-replaced, the ephemeral IP goes away and forces a manual A Record update. What's the "best practice" approach?

Comment: Just saw this http://serverfault.com/questions/705588/how-to-choose-the-external-ip-address-of-a-kubernetes-load-balancer-in-google-co looking forward to v1.1

Comment: Did you find a good way of doing it? I had to add the ingress IP to the DNS record sets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you saw - this will be explicitly supported in v1.1